# Single count query taking too much time postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

```
explain analyze  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "customers" WHERE (TRIM(telephone) = 
'06868787878' AND check_id = 41); 

                          QUERY PLAN                                                                      
------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
------------------------------------------------------------------- 
Aggregate  (cost=12982.58..12982.59 rows=1 width=0) (actual 
time=200.452..200.453 rows=1 loops=1) 
->  Bitmap Heap Scan on customers  (cost=544.59..12982.21 rows=147 width=0) 
(actual time=14.555..200.447 rows=1 loops=1) 
     Recheck Cond: (check_id = 41) 
     Filter: (btrim((telephone)::text) = '06868787878'::text) 
     Rows Removed by Filter: 29394 
     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_customers_check_id  (cost=0.00..544.55 
   rows=29350 width=0) (actual time=9.669..9.669 rows=29395 loops=1) 
           Index Cond: (check_id = 41) 
  Total runtime: 200.750 ms 
 (8 rows)
```

also sometimes its taking (293.6ms), (1956.3ms), is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends quite a bit on your schema and your use patterns, but there are a few things to try.

1. Trim your telephone numbers as they're entered into the DB rather than when you do this count. When you use `TRIM` during the count, the DB has to run it on every row it's evaluating, which is wasteful. If you guarantee your numbers are always trimmed, you can do a simpler `telephone = '06868787878'` check. If that's common, make sure there's an index on `telephone`.
2. If you can't or don't want to trim your `telephone` data before the query, [create an index on the expression](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/indexes-expressional.html) `TRIM(telephone)`. This effectively precomputes all the work `TRIM` is doing, but obviously is only helpful looking up `TRIM(telephone) = '123'`, not `telephone = '123'` on its own anymore.
3. Put your indices on the most specific columns you can. Eg. if `check_id` is only `41` in 2 rows, Postgres can use that index first to narrow down the set, then it has very little work to do verifying the rest of your conditions. If `check_id` is often `41`, but `telephone` is only infrequently `06868787878`, the same applies, and you should have your index on `telephone`. If both are pretty evenly distributed and this is a common query pattern, maybe you want a [multicolumn index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/indexes-multicolumn.html) on `(check_id, telephone)`. Following the same reasoning as with single-column indices, put the more specific column first, or if you also need to filter on just one of the columns, put that one first. Eg. the `(check_id, telephone)` index lets you efficiently query for the `check_id` prefix too.

   3b. Creating a multicolumn index that covers all of your conditions can be quite efficient, since Postgres can use just the index to perform counts, without having to perform a secondary lookup to get the main record and check conditions not covered by the index.